# difference between visual studio 2022 rc version and regular visal studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio-2022

Does anyone know what is difference between visual studio 2022 RC version and regular visual studio 2022, are there any differences or they are the same? I have VS 2022 RC version, so do I need to install regular version?

Comment: Bug fixes, they don't add new features to RC.  Yes, you like bug fixes.  Updates do get spelled out, [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes-preview).

Comment: RC (release candidate) is how Microsoft call its beta-quality software, while the "regular" is the final, production-ready version. Expect mostly bugfixes between them.

Answer (score 0):

RC is release candidate version, it was coupled with .NET 6 release candidate version.
I have installed the "regular" (current) VS 2022 version" as I needed the .NET 6 official version.